# Questions about constant operator in TLA+

Tags: distributed-system, tla+, formalize

I am reading book "Specifying Systems" recently. In Chapter 5, Leslie define constant operator Send(*,*,*,*).

I am confused about how to assign value (True/False) to this constant expression? Do we need to assign True/False to every (p, v, m, m') in the TLC model checker?

Answer (score 2):

You can assign to `Send` in two ways:

1. If you instantiate it in another module, you can pass in the operator you want with `WITH`: `Instance Foo WITH Send <- Op \*...`
2. You can assign an operator in TLC, under "What is the model?"